# pdf file can not be read when executing in fastApi and ghostscript removing pages corrupts the pdf

Tags: python, pdf, ghostscript, fastapi, text-extraction

For my recent project, I'm removing all pages from a PDF except from the title page using ghostscript. Then i'm reading the PDF file and extracting the text from the document.

When i execute it from a notebook it works fine for all PDF's i tested.
When i execute it from my FastApi myapp.py, the text from the original file can not be extracted - results in an exception caused by pdftoppm - and the file manipulated with ghostscript is completely white and all text that gets extracted is '\x0c'.
Same happens when i deploy the application as a docker image.

textract version 1.6.3
fastapi version 0.68.0
ghostscript version 9.53.3

The code i use locally:

```
    responses_list2 = list()
    
    for document in all_sopos:
        print(document)
        tmp_split = os.path.split(document)
        outfile_name = os.path.join(tmp_split[0], "gs_test/tmp_"+tmp_split[1])
        
        
        subprocess.check_output(['gs',
                                '-dBATCH', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dSAFER', '-dFirstPage=1', '-dLastPage=1', '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', 
                                 f'-sOUTPUTFILE={outfile_name}', document])
        
        responses_list2.append((document, numberExtractor.start_extraction(outfile_name)))
        os.remove(outfile_name)
```

The code from myapp.py

```
    def getTypeAheads(documentType: str = Form(...),file: UploadFile = File(...)):
        if allowed_file(file.filename):
            logging.info("Is allowed file.")
            file_object = file.file
            f_dest = open(file.filename, 'wb')
            shutil.copyfileobj(file_object, f_dest)
            #strip to one page only
            outfile_name = f"tmp_{file.filename}"
            subprocess.check_output(['gs',
                                     '-dBATCH', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dSAFER', '-dFirstPage=1', '-dLastPage=1', '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite',
                                     f'-sOUTPUTFILE={outfile_name}', file.filename])
            logging.info("file saved with 1 page.")
            data = numberExtractor.start_extraction(outfile_name)
            logging.info("file extracted, deleting now.")
            os.remove(file.filename)
            os.remove(outfile_name)
            return data
```

Func i use to extract text:

```
    def _load_document_text(self, path, method): 
            encoded_text = textract.process(path, method = method)
            return encoded_text.decode("utf-8")
```

The log output if i let FastAPI extract text from the complete PDF file:

```
    ERROR:uvicorn.error:Exception in ASGI application
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 373, in run_asgi
        result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
        return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 208, in __call__
        await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
        await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
        raise exc from None
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
        await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
        raise exc from None
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
        await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
        await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 241, in handle
        await self.app(scope, receive, send)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 52, in app
        response = await func(request)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 219, in app
        raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 154, in run_endpoint_function
        return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 40, in run_in_threadpool
        return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "/Users/simon/Documents/coac/external/Merck/Versum/merck-focus/ai-server/myapp.py", line 51, in getTypeAheads
        data = numberExtractor.start_extraction(file.filename)
      File "/Users/simon/Documents/coac/external/Merck/Versum/merck-focus/ai-server/classes/NumberExtraction.py", line 113, in start_extraction
        response = self.extraction(path, "tesseract")
      File "/Users/simon/Documents/coac/external/Merck/Versum/merck-focus/ai-server/classes/NumberExtraction.py", line 88, in extraction
        text_data = self._load_document_text(path, method)
      File "/Users/simon/Documents/coac/external/Merck/Versum/merck-focus/ai-server/classes/NumberExtraction.py", line 24, in _load_document_text
        encoded_text = textract.process(path, method = method)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/textract/parsers/__init__.py", line 77, in process
        return parser.process(filename, encoding, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/textract/parsers/utils.py", line 46, in process
        byte_string = self.extract(filename, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/textract/parsers/pdf_parser.py", line 33, in extract
        return self.extract_tesseract(filename, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/textract/parsers/pdf_parser.py", line 57, in extract_tesseract
        stdout, _ = self.run(['pdftoppm', filename, base])
      File "/Users/simon/opt/anaconda3/envs/VersumAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/textract/parsers/utils.py", line 100, in run
        raise exceptions.ShellError(
    textract.exceptions.ShellError: The command `pdftoppm Sales order.pdf /var/folders/z4/c89ns8j910zbl_p8cvfbgq6h0000gn/T/tmp8ou9yrvi/conv` failed with exit code 1
    ------------- stdout -------------
    b''------------- stderr -------------
    b"Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary\nSyntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary\nSyntax Error: Couldn't read xref table\n"
```

So my question is, does anyone know where the mistake in myapp.py is?
I guess it must be there, because it is working from the notebook.

Comment: There's a space in the "command failed" from `textract`. Are you sure that library handles the path correctly? Do not under any circumstances trust the `.filename` property - do not use it directly in a path - as it arrives from the client and can be manipulated in any way the client see fit.

Comment: Ok, thank you @mats. Which other property should i then use from the incoming file to work with it?

Comment: You already use `file.file` to work with it - you can use the tempfile module https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html to create temporary files; otherwise you'd usually want to create a row in a database and get an identifier you control back, then use that identifier to store the file (and then resolve the actual file name from the database if necessary)